# Form of the grand potential

Tags: statistical-mechanics

Let $\Phi$ be the grand potential. The typical argument goes that 
$$\Phi(T, \lambda V, \mu) = \lambda\Phi(T, V, \mu) \implies \Phi = -p(T, \mu)V$$
why do we rule out the possibility that 
$$\Phi = -p’(T,V, \mu)V?$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grand_potential#Grand_potential_for_homogeneous_systems_.28vs._inhomogeneous_systems.29

Comment: Because the $f$-term is not an [extensive quantity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_and_extensive_properties).

Answer (score 1):

Let's suppose that 
$$\Phi = -p(T, \mu)V + f(T, \mu)$$

When one uses $\Phi(T, \lambda V, \mu) = \lambda\Phi(T, V, \mu)$ with $\lambda = 0$, one reaches
$$\Phi(T,0,\mu) = 0$$

So
$$0 =  \Phi(T,0,\mu) = -p(T,\mu)\times 0 + f(T,\mu) = f(T, \mu)$$

So $$f(T,\mu) = 0$$

In the end,
$$ \Phi = -p(T, \mu)V $$